Checking for errors after unplugging a drive without ejecting
I had a few external drives (HDD, flash) plugged into my PC that weren't ejecting, even when using LockHunter (errors), restart, or shut down (would just hang).
I had to go to the airport, so after 10 minutes of it just hanging on the start of the shutting down process, and checking to ensure the lights on the drives weren't "flickering" (which I've surmised usually indicates data being read/written), I pulled the plug on the drives, at which point the PC immediately proceeded to shut down. (I don't recall ever having this issue before; of course it had to happen at an inconvenient time).
The next time I plugged in one of the drives (HDD) on a laptop I usually use, it behaved fine, but on subsequent times, including on another PC and another laptop, although it was readable and writable in Explorer, the option to eject it had disappeared, and it showed up in device settings as an "Unknown device". After a quick search on resolving this, I re-downloaded the driver for the device which immediately resolved that issue, and so far it seems to be behaving normally again.
I am copying all of the files onto another drive as a backup. How can I be sure that unplugging the drive did not cause other undetected issues (e.g. corruption) beyond possibly this driver problem?
Would chkdsk /f or /r help? There's a lot of data (multiple TB) which would take time to check, so would like to be sure that whatever tool/process is something worth running on it.

It hasn’t been necessary to “safely eject” flash drives for nearly a decade due to built-in safe guards to Windows. The only asterisk is that you shouldn’t remove the drive as you are purposely moving data to the drive. In fact the “safety ejection” mechanic as actively been changed/removed since the release of Windows 10

@Ramhound Thanks, I figured the flash drive was probably fine. Wondering more about the portable HDD the driver issue occurred with.

I don’t know what drivers you installed. Mass storage USB device drivers are built-into Windows. It should not be necessary to install mass storage device drivers.

@Ramhound Western Digital WD SES Driver 12.07 for Windows 64-bit

Those drivers are for only advanced features like control over the LEDs they are also legacy and I wouldn’t trust them to be functional on Windows 10+ so unless you really need those advanced features I would not install them. Given the age of those drivers I suspect you dealing with a drive that is several years old. It’s entirely possible your issues are simply hardware related

BTW, on some PC's using external HDD's, which are not always treated by Windows as removable media (sans write cache), I find a third-party tool, such as HotSwap! (http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm) or alternatives (https://alternativeto.net/software/hotswap/) useful. As mentioned above, if the OS is in the process of writing to the device, pulling it out can destroy a flash drive or damage HDD.
